# how do I call my theme preprocess function for a specific field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, task-parallel-library

i'm on Drupal 7 and i have aspecific tpl.php file for a content field_image: "field--field_image.tpl.php". I need to create a preprocess function for this field and for my theme.

Supposing my theme name is "My Theme"

It should look like

```
function my_theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'aClassName';
}
```

but it doesn't work. I am wrong. But where?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`template_preprocess_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) (like you do in your code above) but just test the particular field is the right one for you:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (isset($element['#field_name'])) {
    if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_image') {
      $variables['classes_array'][] = 'aClassName';
    }
  }
}
```

Once you've implemented the hook don't forget to clear your caches, hook implementations are cached in Drupal 7 so won't be picked up until the cache is cleared.

Comment: Thanks.

After clearing all caches i can't see any changes where there should be. I can't find any 'aClassName' class in the field_image...

The problem is printing items with <?php print render($item); ?> ?

Comment: put a call to `drupal_set_message('TEST');` at the top of the function and refresh the page a couple of times - if you don't see the 'TEST' message then the hook isn't being called. If that's the case then the best you can do is disabled the theme and re-enable it to see if Drupal then picks up the hook. Out of interest do you have any other preprocess/hook functions along with this one in your `template.php` file?

Comment: Finally! After disabling and re-enabling the theme I got the hook to be called. Thank you!
and btw yes, I got a lot of preprocess fuctions!

Comment: I'm having a heck of a time getting Drupal to recognize this function with a custom form.

Answer (score 4):

You could declare a `mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook)` in your theme's template.php where you can check your field and do operations on its label or markup, add classes, anything. So you wouldn't need field specific tpls. - eg.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_machine_name') {
        $variables['items'][0]['#markup'] = 'add custom markup';
  }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: How does this improve on Clive's answer, posted before yours, with more detail?

Answer (score -4):

In drupal 7 you can rewrite output of the field in template_preprocess_node() by altering "#markup" value of the field.

Also you can use regexp to change whatever you want in page content :)